Explicit this object parameter wonkiness
There was some code floating around on Reddit that defined a member-function with an explicit this object parameter defined as type int. This made me wonder how this member-function could possibly be invoked.
After doing some tests, all of the compilers (Clang, GCC, and MSVC) seem to produce different results. So, this raises the question; is the following code legal and in accordance with the C++23 standard?
struct w { constexpr bool f(this int) { return true; } };
static_assert((*&w::f)(1)); // clang ok, gcc ok, msvc nope
static_assert((*&w::f)(0)); // clang ok, gcc nope, msvc nope

Demo

GCC's error message:
<source>:3:23: error: non-constant condition for static assertion
    3 | static_assert((*&w::f)(0));
      |               ~~~~~~~~^~~
<source>:3:24: error: dereferencing a null pointer
    3 | static_assert((*&w::f)(0));
      |   

MSVC's error message:
<source>(2): error C2660: 'w::f': function does not take 1 arguments
<source>(1): note: see declaration of 'w::f'
<source>(2): note: while trying to match the argument list '(int)'
<source>(3): error C2660: 'w::f': function does not take 1 arguments
<source>(1): note: see declaration of 'w::f'
<source>(3): note: while trying to match the argument list '(int)'


What is this code trying to accomplish? In any case, this doesn't seem legal since a this parameter (implicit or explicit) refers to the object that the method is being called on, and you can't call methods on an int value.

w::f is a method that takes as its first parameter a pointer to a w object as an int and returns true in a constexpr way?

I think Clang is correct, &w::f undoubtedly gives a function pointer of type bool (*)(int).

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont I can't find anything prohibiting this use. In fact, user-defined conversions are permitted on the explicit object parameter. So something like struct A : w { operator int(); }; A a; a.f(); should be allowed.

@RemyLebeau See above.

@user17732522 Good question.  Now that I look at it more closely, I've changed my mind.

@康桓瑋 w::f is a non-static member method, so the pointer type of &w::f would be bool (w::*)(int) instead.

@RemyLebeau That's not true. The first parameter is this int, not int.

The proposal itself seems to make this int invalid. It says: "We propose a new way of declaring a member function that will allow for deducing the type and value category of the class instance parameter, while still being invocable as a member function." Note the emphasis on class instance parameter which this int is not.

@康桓瑋 either way, my point is that it would be (w::*) (pointer to member of w) not (*) (pointer to free function)

@user12002570 It does not seem to make this int invalid - that sentence just describes one thing the proposal allows you to do, it is just the only thing the proposal allows you to do. There is even an example that we added that demonstrates that this works. (source: my paper).

@Barry I see. Wasn't aware of that example in the original paper.

GCC issue reported: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=115878

@RemyLebeau, actually &w::f here has the same type as the pointer to free function: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/aG6bEPxsd

@Fedor why? f is a non-static method

@RemyLebeau, I think it is the same as in the last example for Explicit object member functions: “pg” is not a pointer to member function

@RemyLebeau Since C++23, because of the addition of explicit object parameters, a lot of statements that originally were true for all non-static member functions are now only true for implicit object non-static member functions. Non-static member functions with explicit object parameters are somewhere between the old non-static member functions and static member functions in terms of behavior.

@user17732522 ok, thanks

I also think Clang is the only compiler behaving correctly here.
this int in itself is fine. I do not see any restrictions on the type of the explicit object parameter.
&w::f is clearly defined to give a bool(*)(int) pointing to the member function.
(*&w::f)(1) and (*&w::f)(0) should then be normal calls that match the call arguments in order to the parameters of the function, so 1 or 0 will be the argument to the explicit object parameter. There won't be any problem with the call as 1 and 0 can be used as arguments for an int parameter.
So it looks to me like bugs in GCC and MSVC.

So, w::f is a non-static member-function that, when taking its address (i.e. &w::f), gives back a function pointer of type bool(*)(int)? Which section of the C++23 standard describes this behavior?

Also, could you please quote/reference the section of the C++23 standard that determines the invocation of (*&w::f)(0) as well-defined?

This answer seems wrong. The program is ill-formed for the reason explained in my answer. Also this isn't a language-lawyered answer.

@303 There is no w type object here on which the function is called making the program ill-formed.

@303 Maybe a bug in the standard. For example, it is not possible to call your given function f from outside the class. For example, see demo where int main(){w obj; obj.f(10);} won't work.

@user12002570 In that example the compilers complain that they expect 0 arguments, yet 1 is provided (the integer literal). However, if you omit that argument and provide w with an implicit conversion operator to int, all compilers accept the function call, see demo.

@303 Yup that looks weird. As to call a non-static member function we'll have to provide a conversion operator.

@303 See https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#3 and https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call#6.sentence-1.

@user12002570 Obviously obj.f(10) doesn't work. The whole point of explicit object parameters is that it shall be matched against the object expression (obj), not the first argument of the call via member access expression. You didn't leave any parameter to take the 10 argument.

@user17732522 Yes, that is my point that with explicit object member function we can't have two explicit object parameter. In other words, we can't add this w as first parameter to make it work.

@Alan I do not see any reason that a w object has to be used to call the function.

@user12002570 Nevermind, I think I am missing some context from the discussion. Maybe a deleted comment from 303?

@user17732522 I think you're not missing any comments. Currently me or they haven't deleted any comments from here.

@user17732522 If this were allowed then this would make f behave the same way as a static member function I mean a static member function also has a normal function pointer type and it can be called without ant object. That will defeat the whole purpose of having f as a non-static member function.

@user17732522 Note thatthe proposal seems to make this int invalid.The proposal says: "We propose a new way of declaring a member function that will allow for deducing the type and value category of the class instance parameter, while still being invocable as a member function. We introduce a new kind of parameter that can be provided as the first parameter to any member function: an explicit object parameter. The purpose of this parameter is to bind to the implicit object, allowing it to be deduced."

@user17732522 I've added the same as a note in my answer.

@user12002570 That is motivation, not text.  It can make nothing invalid.  It can imply something is unexpected; but we already know that.

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont Note that I explicitly say in my answer "the above was only the intention of the proposal. Below is given what is currently in the standard wording." and then I explain what is in the current wording. I'll highlight(italicize it)

(*&w::f)(0) is undefined behavior because it requires this to be nullptr

@Gene There is (maybe confusingly) no this in an explicit object non-static member function. There is, contrary to normally calling an implicit object non-static member function, also no dereferencing of any object involved when using the function pointer syntax (*&w::f)(0).

@Gene The dereferencing is the only reason that a call to an implicit object non-static member function on a null pointer can syntactically happen and cause UB, i.e. x->f() can potentially be UB because p->f() is transformed to (*p)->f() and *p is UB if p is a null pointer value. That this can't be a null pointer value in an implicit object non-static member function is a consequence of that and the fact that no other syntax exists that could make this a null pointer in such a function. (In a call via pointer-to-member-function the same dereferencing happens syntactically.)

@Gene But in (*&w::f)(0) there is no dereferencing. And 0 isn't used to initialize any this or other pointer anyway. It instead initializes the explicit object parameter of type int.

@user17732522 -- I take it back, I'm more confused with gcc now that after complaining about null in static_assert it accepts return (*&w::f)(0);

This is CWG2688 that points out that currently [expr.call] does not properly handle explicit object member functions.
Note the issue is still open.
From CWG2688:



Section: 7.6.1.3  [expr.call]
Status: open
Submitter: Matthew House
Date: 2023-01-16




Subclause 7.6.1.3 [expr.call] paragraphs 1 and 2 do not properly handle explicit object member functions. Such a function can be called via a function pointer, via an lvalue obtained by dereferencing a function pointer, and via a class member access expression.


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
